# How can i get last row of specific id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get last row of specific id in mysql. Let suppose i have a table user products

```
    userProducts

    id | user_id  | products 
    1 | 12| Mouse
    2 | 12| Keyboard
    3 | 12| Laptop
    4 | 12| Headphone
    5 | 12| Webcame
```

I want to get last row Webcame of `user_id=12`. Please guide me how can i customize this query for that.

```
select * from userProducts where user_id = 12
```

Comment: Use `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to sort by id and limit resultset:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userProducts
WHERE user_id = 12
ORDER BY id  DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Add a subquery:

```
select * from userProducts 
where user_id = 12 
and id = (
 select max(id) from userProducts where user_id = 12
);
```